# Select from 2 tables by repeating the rows from the second to each row in the first

Tags: sql-server, sql

I have a situation that I want to simplify it this way. (I'm writing this in Sql Server)

Imagine I have 2 tables as following:

**Books**

+---------+
| BookID |
+---------+
|     1      |
+---------+
|     2      |
+---------+
|     3      |
+---------+

**BookRentals**

+---------+-------------+---------------+
| BookID |   RentedBy  | RentalDate  |
+---------+-------------+---------------+
|      1     |         A      | 1/1/2015      |
+---------+-------------+---------------+
|      2     |         A      | 2/1/2015      |
+---------+-------------+---------------+
|      1     |         B      | 3/1/2015      |
+---------+-------------+---------------+
|      3     |         B      | 4/1/2015      |
+---------+-------------+---------------+

I need to write a select statement that produces the following result:

+---------+-------------+---------------+
| BookID |   RentedBy  | RentalDate  |
+---------+-------------+---------------+
|      1     |         A      | 1/1/2015      |
+---------+-------------+---------------+
|      2     |         A      | 2/1/2015      |
+---------+-------------+---------------+
|      3     |         A      |      NULL      |
+---------+-------------+---------------+
|      1     |         B      | 2/1/2015      |
+---------+-------------+---------------+
|      2     |         B      |       NULL      |
+---------+-------------+---------------+
|      3     |         B      | 2/1/2015      |
+---------+-------------+---------------+

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: look into `left outer join`

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want a cross join of all books and all renters, adding a column that displays the RentalDate (if any) for a given combination of BookID and Renter?

Try this:

```
SELECT B.BookId, R.RentedBy, BR.RentalDate
FROM Books AS B
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT RentedBy FROM BookRentals) AS R
LEFT JOIN BookRentals AS BR ON BR.BookId = B.BookId AND BR.RentedBy = R.RentedBy
```

If you already have a table containing the ID of all renters, you might want to use that, instead of the subquery `(SELECT DISTINCT RentedBy FROM BookRentals)`.

Comment: Good answer. You shouldn't mix implicit and explicit joins though. Replace `FROM Books AS B, ...` with `FROM Books AS B CROSS JOIN ...` to use explicit joins only.